# Is there a command to update redis?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, redis

I'm working on the front end for a web app, but I'm trying to learn as much of the backend setup as I can as well. I am setting up redis on a new computer myself, but running into a few hiccups.

The wget command cannot be found, so I assume it Linux only? I am following [these instructions](https://redistogo.com/documentation/introduction_to_redis) to install redis on Mac OS 10.7. I have redis 2.0.0 installed, but while attempting to install 2.4.4 using the same commands, I am told redis-server, redis-cli, redis-benchmark cannot be found, and I can't copy them to /usr/local/bin.

I could not find an update command to bring redis up to the most recent version. I don't think it should be this difficult to install the most recent version on redis on Mac OS, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

So far as I know, typing:

```
    $ brew upgrade redis
```

should work, where $ indicates your command line.  If it complains about HomeBrew not being installed, you can obtain that [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew).  Brew is an excellent package manager, and a great way of taking care of your files.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot I had homebrew installed before. MAkes everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 10):

If you're not using brew, then these steps will help you get up to date.

First, find the location of your installed redis-server instance before updating. In my case, it was in `/usr/local/bin/`, but it might also be in `/usr/bin/`. If it's not here, you can type `which redis-server` to find the location.

Next, download the redis tar file from https://redis.io/download, then install it from the directory it downloaded to:

```
cd Downloads
tar xzf redis-X.Y.Z.tar.gz
cd redis-X.Y.Z
make test
make
```

Next, we'll move the new installed redis to the location where the current instance is running:

```
sudo mv src/redis-server /usr/local/bin
sudo mv src/redis-cli /usr/local/bin
```

Now you should be ready to use redis-server and redis-cli in the new version.

PS - I also moved the redis-benchmark, redis-sentinel, redis-check-aof, and redis-check-dump files because they were also already in `/usr/local/bin`.

Ref: http://jasdeep.ca/2012/05/installing-redis-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 6):

It would be better to follow this way.

`$ brew update`

`$brew upgrade redis`

Comment: $brew upgrade redis  will automatically run an update on brew first.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bash file...

```
cd ~
nano .update_redis
```

Go into the tmp directory and download the latest stable version

```
cd /tmp
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
```

Decompress the files

```
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
```

Compile

```
cd redis-stable
make
```

Copy the bin programs

```
cp src/redis-cli /usr/bin/
cp src/redis-server /usr/bin/
cp src/redis-benchmark /usr/bin/
```

Set Permissions

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/redis-cli
chmod 755 /usr/bin/redis-server
chmod 755 /usr/bin/redis-benchmark
```

Execute

```
bash .update_redis
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing an answer that doesn't rely on Homebrew, but could you add more detail around what the "paste this" block does? There are a lot of steps there, and developers should know what they are doing before executing all of it.